# Bootstrap collapsible table rows need their 'hidden' size to be default

Tags: html, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question was very hard for me to word. Basically, I've created a table which hides rows using Bootstrap's `collapse` class. I have a row which is the 'parent' row, and then under each 'parent' there are a bunch of 'child' rows. The issue I'm having is that the width of each column is determined by width of the fields of the parent row, until I expand then the width of each column is changed to adjust to the child rows.

Here's what I'm talking about. We'll start with what it looks like collapsed:

[image]

And then expanded:

[image]

As you can see, the width of the columns adjust depending on whether the child rows are hidden or not. This is very jarring to the eyes, as the data you are looking at just shifts around on you.

So what I would like to happen is when the data is brought in, the width of the columns is **always** determined like the child rows are visible, even if they are not.

Apparently you can't post HTML without it just getting actually parsed as HTML. The HTML is generated by quite a bit of ugly JavaScript code. The resulting HTML (which I can't even copy as it's sent through an AJAX call) is simple enough though.
The chevron button has a `data-toggle` for `collapse` pointing at its respective children rows. The children rows have class `collapse` and one other class I just use for identifying the children rows with their parent row.

If anybody has any suggestions, that would be amazing. Thanks in advance! If any more information is needed, just let me know.

Comment: You can post HTML inside of code tags. If you can put together a http://www.bootply.com/new# with sampled data showing your problem I am sure many people will help.

Comment: You CAN post code here, using {} in the input window. And a bootply showing the issue really would be ideal...

Comment: I used the code formatting, and it still stripped out my HTML. I would use Bootply, but it apparently does not work with our version of IE, and we're not allowed to download any other browser.

The issue is simple. The width of the columns in the table changes when you collapse and un-collapse the rows. It's most obvious with the first two columns, and the last three columns.

Comment: `@Jready` You can add column fixed by css like `.table{table-layout: fixed;}` from this  table-layout:fixed to your column will not resize on collapse.

Answer (score 1):

I used this **.table{table-layout: fixed;}** css property for column fixed and after collapsing event trigger `hidden row` column render as `parent column width size`.
I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
.table{table-layout: fixed;}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Col</th>
            <th>Col</th>
            <th>Col</th>
            <th>Col</th>
            <th>Col</th>
            <th>Col</th>
            <th>Col</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".record1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>001</td>
            <td>2020-28-1</td>
            <td>2020-28-1</td>
            <td>A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="collapse record1">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Max and Amount</td>
            <td>Max and amount per unit</td>
            <td>Pay code</td>
            <td>Rav commit code</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsome</td>
            <td>Lob Code</td>
            <td>Lob criteria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="collapse record1">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Max and Amount</td>
            <td>Max and amount per unit</td>
            <td>Pay code</td>
            <td>Rav commit code</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsome</td>
            <td>Lob Code</td>
            <td>Lob criteria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="collapse record1">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Max and Amount</td>
            <td>Max and amount per unit</td>
            <td>Pay code</td>
            <td>Rav commit code</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsome</td>
            <td>Lob Code</td>
            <td>Lob criteria</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- // -->
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".record2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>09876</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>002</td>
            <td>2020-29-1</td>
            <td>2020-29-1</td>
            <td>B</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="collapse record2">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Max and Amount</td>
            <td>Max and amount per unit</td>
            <td>Pay code</td>
            <td>Rav commit code</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsome</td>
            <td>Lob Code</td>
            <td>Lob criteria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="collapse record2">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Max and Amount</td>
            <td>Max and amount per unit</td>
            <td>Pay code</td>
            <td>Rav commit code</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsome</td>
            <td>Lob Code</td>
            <td>Lob criteria</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```